# What is the output of this program

Tags: c

Please explain output of this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    x ^= x || x++ || ++x || x++;

    printf("\n%d",x);
}
```

O/p is 3 (http://codepad.org/X49j0etz)

```
According to me output should be 2.
as || is a sequence point as far as i remember.
so expression becomes.

x ^= 0 || 0 || 2 || 2;

so after evaluation of this expression(x || x++ || ++x || x++;) x becomes 3
x  = 3 ^ 1
so x becomes 2;
```

Comment: Its in C language so ^ operator is EX_OR operation not power.

Comment: @AlterMann: You were right: There's UB because `x` is modified twice without sequence point (once once on the right and once through the compound assignment).

Comment: @KerrekSB According to Associativity and precedence table. this expression x ^= x || x++ || ++x || x++; becomes x = x ^ ( x || (x++)||(++x)||x++; is this right?

Comment: Sort of, but that has the same UB, since you're modifying `x` twice without intervening sequence point.

Comment: Both logical OR and semicolon are sequence points

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: Since `x ^= x++` is UB, clearly this is too.

Comment: "Both logical OR and semicolon are sequence points " -- but `^=` isn't. The `++` can be applied before or after that operation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the answers claiming undefined behaviour are correct, but there is also a simple explanation for how you can arrive at the result of 3.

Just consider that the last `x++` is never evaluated because the last `||` operation short-circuits, and let's assume that the side effects are applied before the ^= is evaluated. Then you are left with

```
x = 2 ^ 1;
```

Unsurprisingly resulting in 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is an undefined behavior in c. Because we cannot predict in which direction the expression is evaluated